# models django adding new feild and getting intigrity error:

Tags: django-models

This is my models :

class UserSubs(models.Model):

```
subscription_start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
plan_start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None)   ## adding new feild by me 
current_period_start = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
current_period_end = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
canceled_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

when applying migrate command error getting and error :

**IntegrityError: column "plan_start_date" of relation "subscription_usersubs" contains null values**

i have tried adding Null true as well but this still shows

Answer (score 0):

I feel some values in the plan_start_date column are having NULL values.

If there are NULL values then kindly make your column accept NULL Value by executing the following command on your table:

```
ALTER TABLE subscription_usersubs ALTER COLUMN plan_start_date SET NOT NULL;
```

Or you can apply a technique that best fits your scenario.